# Custom Visual Studio skins per TFS branch

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I'm interested in what methods people use to help visual identification of different branches of essentially the same solution.
 We are changing our processes for modifying our product so that we have several different branches of the same code. Its not immediately obvious which branch you are in unless you check the path of the solution. The ideal scenario would be for the name of the branch to be visible at the top of the visual studio statusbar, or if a different coloured skin could be used for each instance branch. i.e. branch A has a green menubar and branch B has a red menubar.

Answer (score 1):

What I do is to open the history of the branch I'm currently on. That way, I can see each VS instance's name in the tab in the bar ("History - Dev1").

EDIT:

Maybe I can explain myself better (my limited english difficults this :P).

If you open the History window of a branch (in the Source Control Explorer, right click the Branch and pick "View History"), a new tab is placed in the upper bar (I don't know how to call it; is the bar that holds the tabs for every file you have open at any time). That tab is called "History - Branchname".  Well, if you leave the History Window opened, you can see the name of the current branch just by looking at the tab in the bar. That way, just open the right history window in each VS instance and you'll have a way for quickly know the branch of each instance ("History - Dev1", "History - Test", etc.).

Comment: do you mean the tfs history window? I could check by highlighting the solution file in visualstudio and i can see the path property which tells me but i was hoping for a method of me very easily being able to see if im in the wrong solution or not for example.